# How to make access-text-underscores always visible in menu items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard, menuitem

Normally the underscores for access texts are only visible when a menu has been accessed via keyboard input (e.g. the top menu via <kbd>Alt</kbd> or a context-menu via the menu key).

I would like to add an option to an application to make them always visible to make it easier to use mouse and keyboard in combination (mouse to point and open a specific context menu, keyboard to execute a certain item on that menu).

Possibly there is a simple way of doing this, possibly not, at the very least it does not seem obvious to me...

Comment: With Win XP and above, its controlled by the OS level settings (`Desktop > Properties > Appearance > Effects`). Not sure if this can be overridden programatically. Even if it could, it probably won't be a good UX (personally I wouldn't like such an app).

Comment: @Mrchie: Really? Most applications i've seen *always* display the access text. (Also as i said, i'd only make it an option for those who want it)

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to see those underscores and some app shows them anyway, would you like that? Even if you make it optional, you're now making me go change the setting in your app again (assuming that I somehow know there is setting for this in your app), even when I have set my preference at the OS level already.

Comment: @Mrchie: I never said that the option would be enabled by default...

Comment: Now _that_ is bearable to me! In fact, I would now like your app because I can enable it just for your app (coz I love it so much now and no sarcasm here) without enabling it for everyone! :)