# How to show AccessKey without pressing Alt in WPF?

Tags: wpf, shortcut

I am using `AccessText` to show my text, where I need my Access Key should display by default without pressing Alt key. The Insert Table dialog (Office 2010) in MS word contains text which showing Access keys by default. I need such thing.

Is there any possibility?

Regards

Jawahar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make access-text-underscores always visible in menu items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959814/how-to-make-access-text-underscores-always-visible-in-menu-items)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a windows setting. If u are using win7 look at the following.

[OS_forum](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1404600.htm)

Comment: It probably is a Windows setting. I think thought that the O.P. is asking how to do it regardless of the setting in Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can kind of fool the UI.

```
<Button x:Name="btnAccessG" Height="40" Width="100" Click="btnAccess_Click">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />  
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <AccessText Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="White">btn_AccessG</AccessText>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Visible">btn<Underline>A</Underline>ccessG</TextBlock>
    </Grid>          
</Button>
```

Setting `AccessText Visible = Hidden` does not work.