# Is there a way to make the _ appear for hotkeys without the Alt key?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hotkeys

In WPF when you make a label like this:

```
<Label Content="_My Label"/>
```

Then when you run the app and press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key it will show the "M" underlined.

We have our own custom hotkey Attached Property that allows us to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Problem is that only <kbd>Alt</kbd> will show the underscores.

Is there a way to show the underscore when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed?

NOTE: I do NOT want to send a programmatic <kbd>Alt</kbd> KeyPress in the background when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed.  That will just confuse my shortcut system.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959814/how-to-make-access-text-underscores-always-visible-in-menu-items

Comment: As @Slaks says, it's an option for the file Explorer part of Windows.

Comment: @SLaks - it is an option to make the Ctrl key turn it on just like the Alt key?  I knew there was an option for it to just be on all the time.  I did not know of one that will make it activate for the Ctrl key as my question states.  Can you please point me to it? (post it as answer and I will accept it.)

Comment: try this workaroud: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588004/how-to-show-accesskey-without-pressing-alt-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I have got a solution to show the `_` for hot-keys without <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed.

### Here is how to Do it :

---

**Small Code to Press a KeyBoard Key dynamically :**

```
//<summary>
//Function to Perform a Keyboard KeyPress.
//</summary>
void PressKey(Key KeyboardKey)
{
    KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.LeftAlt);
    args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args);
}
```

---

**Code to Append and Remove `HotKeyChar` :**

```
//<summary>
//Function to Append a HotKeyChar to a Content of a Control.
//</summary>
void AppendHotKeyChar(ContentControl Ctrl, int KeyIndex)
{
    if (Ctrl.Content.ToString().Substring(KeyIndex, 1) != "_")
    {
        Ctrl.Content = "_" + Ctrl.Content;
    }
}
//<summary>
//Function to Remove a HotKeyChar to a Content of a Control.
//</summary>
void RemoveHotKeyChar(ContentControl Ctrl, int KeyIndex)
{
    if (Ctrl.Content.ToString().Substring(KeyIndex, 1) == "_")
    {
        Ctrl.Content = Ctrl.Content.ToString().Remove(KeyIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

---

**XAML Code for `Button Bt1` :**

```
<Button x:Name="Bt1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

---

**Code for `Window.Loaded` event of the `MainWindow` (e.g. `MainWindow1_Loaded`) :**

```
PressKey(Key.LeftAlt);
```

---

**Code for `Window.KeyDown` event of the `MainWindow` (e.g. `MainWindow1_KeyDown`) :**

```
if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
{
    AppendHotKey(Bt1, 0);
}
```

---

**Code for `Window.KeyUp` event of the `MainWindow` (e.g. `MainWindow1_KeyUp`) :**

```
if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
{
    RemoveHotKey(Bt1, 0);
}
```

---

Now, When you start your app the <kbd>Alt</kbd> will be pressed once dynamically.

And now every-time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, your `Control.Content` will be Appended with a `_` and so the `HotKey` will appear underlined!
But one remark is that you should create `Control.Content` without `HotKeyChar '_'` but keep an `Index` of where your `_` will be appended.

But keep in mind that if <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed again in your app, The code will not work anymore. So, you have to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> again to make the code work!

Best way to appending and removing a `HotKeyChar` :

- Create an instance of `List<KeyValuePair<int, Control>>` to store the `Index` of the `HotKeyChar` and the `Control`.
- And now in the `KeyDown` event just loop through the `KeyValuePair<...>` in the `List<...>`..appending the `_`.
- In the `KeyUp` event again just loop through the `KeyValuePair<...>` in the `List<...>`..removing the `_`.

Hope it Helped!